# How to look up neovim command for existing Vim command?

Tags: neovim, help-system

This is a question about using the help docs. I find Vim's documentation really
easy to navigate, I've done it a lot, and there was the user manual to explain
the system. But I find neovim's documentation really tough! If you wanna look up
how to do `:help map` in Lua, you have to say `:help lua-keymap` or `:help vim.keymap`. You have to know to look up `lua-keymap` or `vim.map`.

Are there resources that help you browse through the Lua help docs? I am really
struggling here. I have been using ChatGPT to look stuff up; it works, but it
kinda sucks. I feel like I'm shooting in the dark every time I go to the docs,
whereas with Vim I felt like everything was there and made sense!

---

Example:

I want to run a Vim command: `highlight Normal guibg=None`. I want to run it in
Lua (because I want to learn the interface fluently, not because I *need* to use
Lua). I can easily do this like so: `vim.cmd("highlight Normal guibg=None")`.

[There's also a neovim way to do
it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73370407/7531823), but I never would have
learned about this if not for Google.